# I want to set TextView text from ViewHolder's itemView clicklistener . I can call companion function. but cant access TextView object from it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to set TextView text from ViewHolder's itemView clicklistener . I tried making companion object in Activity class, and tried calling it from ViewHolders itemView clicklistener. But inside companion object I couldn't access TextView object in layout

Following is the adapter code for setting **recyclerview**

```
class QnAdapter(val context: Context, val ques: List<QnoList>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<QnAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder{
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_qno, p0, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return ques.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int){
    val question = ques[p1]
    p0.setData(question, p1)

}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    var currentQ: QnoList?=null
    var currentQno: Int =0
    init{
        itemView.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(context,currentQ!!.qno.toString()+" Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var a1 = MCQActivity
            a1.setText(context)
            a1.setTxt()  // here I want to set TextView, present in Layout of activity(not of recyclerview) text from recyclerview event 


        }

    }
    fun setData(ques:QnoList?,p1:Int){
        itemView.rqno.text = ques!!.qno.toString()
        this.currentQ = ques
        this.currentQno = p1+1
    }
}
}

private fun MCQActivity.Companion.setTxt() {

TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
 }
```

following is the `activity` class code

```
class MCQActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object {

    fun setText(context: Context){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hi I am called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mcq)

    setRecyclerView()

}

open fun setRecyclerView(){
    val layoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    layoutmanager.orientation= LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
    recycler_qno.layoutManager = layoutmanager
    val adapter = QnAdapter(this, mcq.queslst)
    recycler_qno.adapter = adapter
 }
}
```

Comment: sir if you want to set text to Textview you can set from onBindholder. if your recyclerview contains any button to click then you want to set text to Textview ill provide code for that

Answer (score 0):

Off course you can't access the `TextView` via companion object.

First you should understand the definition of companion object. It is an object that is common to all instances of that class or any other classes. It’d come to be **similar to static fields in Java**. It doesn't have any references to any objects created for that class.

**So how to solve your problem?**

Since you have already passing context to `QnAdapter`, and I suppose it is an instance/object of `MCQActivity`, you can cast that context to `MCQActivity` and set the text for that instance.
Refer to this code

```
class MCQActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun setText(theTextYouWantToSet: String) {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = theTextYouWantToSet
    }
}

class QnAdapter(val context: Context, val ques: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<QnAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                (context as MCQActivity).setText("I am handsome")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `companion` function is the same as a static function in `Java`. In your case, you should remove the companion object and make the `setText` function public in your `MCQActivity`.

To access your activity from `ViewHolder`, it's straightforward:

```
 (itemView.context as? MCQActivity)?.setText("I am handsome")
```